# Hyperlinks.add changes hyperlink unwanted

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have used `hyperlinks.add` several times now and never had any problems with it. 
Now I added a line of code: `SourceBook.Sheets(ESN & "_SV" & SV).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("A" & i), _
Address:=ToPath & NewName` to my base code (which you can find under here). This should add a link to the newly created document.

The problem is that excel always says it cannot open the file. The  link I enter via code is right, as I copied it with `debug.print` and it opened the file without a problem.

It came to my attention that the hyperlink I added was modified by excel when I hold my mouse over the hyperlink. I wonder how this is possible.

A second problem I encounterd is that when I enter the hyperlink manually and navigate manually to the file to make sure it takes the right file, excel still modifies my link and says "cannot open specified file".

Anyone an idea what might go wrong here? Thanks!

Code:

```
`Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i, j, FSO As Object, SV, ESN, PartName, ToPath, FromPath, NewName, MsgBoxAnswer, TargetBook As Workbook, SourceBook As Workbook
Dim OS, PN, SN, ProjectNumber, Customer, StartDate, EndDate, LastRowCMM
ESN = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G2").Value
SV = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("K2").Value
ProjectNumber = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value
Customer = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Value
Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
PGB.Min = 0
PGB.Value = 0
PGB.Max = 22

'Create main folder
If SV <> 1 Then
SV = "(SV " & SV & ")"
ToPath = "U:\tmo\vanmolle\fiches constat\Fiches constats #" & ESN & " " & SV
Else
ToPath = "U:\tmo\vanmolle\fiches constat\Fiches constats #" & ESN
End If
If FSO.folderexists(ToPath) = True Then
MsgBoxAnswer = MsgBox("Folder already created.", vbExclamation, "Folder exists.")
Exit Sub
End If
FSO.createfolder (ToPath)


'Create all Excel files & fill them in
For i = 6 To 27
FromPath = "U:\tmo\VANMOLLE\Fiches constat\Template fiches constat LEAP.xlsm"
If SV <> 1 Then
ToPath = "U:\tmo\vanmolle\fiches constat\Fiches constats #" & ESN & " " & SV & "\"
Else
ToPath = "U:\tmo\vanmolle\fiches constat\Fiches constats #" & ESN & "\"
End If

FSO.copyfile Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
NewName = "#" & ESN & "_" & ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i) & ".xlsm"
If SV <> 1 Then
FromPath = "U:\tmo\vanmolle\fiches constat\Fiches constats #" & ESN & " " & SV & "\Template fiches constat LEAP.xlsm"
Else
FromPath = "U:\tmo\vanmolle\fiches constat\Fiches constats #" & ESN & "\Template fiches constat LEAP.xlsm"
End If

Name FromPath As ToPath & NewName
Set SourceBook = ThisWorkbook
Set TargetBook = Workbooks.Open(ToPath & NewName)
TargetBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
PartName = SourceBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value
OS = SourceBook.ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i).Value
PN = SourceBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value
SN = SourceBook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value
    If SN = "" Then SN = "N/A"
StartDate = SourceBook.ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i).Value
EndDate = SourceBook.ActiveSheet.Range("H" & i).Value

'check for right CMM
'LastRowCMM = TargetBook.Sheets("Révision CMM").Range("B6").End(xlDown).Row
'For j = 1 To LastRowCMM
'If PartName = TargetBook.Sheets("Révision CMM").Range("A" & j).Value Then ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A23").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Révision CMM").Range("B" & j).Value
'Next j

TargetBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B9").Value = PartName
TargetBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Value = OS
TargetBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Value = "# " & ESN
TargetBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B12").Value = PN
TargetBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B13").Value = SN
TargetBook.ActiveSheet.Range("E9").Value = StartDate
TargetBook.ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Value = EndDate
TargetBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B14").Value = ProjectNumber
TargetBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B15").Value = Customer
TargetBook.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$E$39"

TargetBook.Close True

'Add hyperlink
SourceBook.Sheets(ESN & "_SV" & SV).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("A" & i), _
Address:=ToPath & NewName

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Progress.PGB.Value = i - 5
Progress.Lbl.Caption = "File " & i - 5 & " of 22 copied."
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True`
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first - declare each variable explicitly. E.g.:

`Dim i as Long, j as Long, FSO As Object, SV as String, ESN as String` and etc.
The way in your code - `Dim i, j,  SV, ESN, PartName, ToPath` they are declared as variant.

Second thing second - try something really very small to debug further. E.g. write this small piece:

```
Sub TestMe()    
    With Worksheets(1)
      .Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=.Range("A1"), Address:="C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\test.docx"
    End With        
End Sub
```

and check whether it works. If it doesn't, debug further, check whether cells are locked or anything similar.

Comment: Hello,

Started doing that already (the variables), this is one of my first macros :) . The test I did and in print.debug it works, in excel it doesn't. And that's something I've never had before. Cells are not locked and it makes the hyperlinks, it just modifies them